# Ant style wild card path string matching in groovy

Tags: groovy, ant

Below is the scenario:

Case(1):

```
String patternStr = "hello/*"
 // This is the pattern supplied

String s1 = "hello/text"       

String s2 = "hello/text/abcd"
```

I need to compare the above strings **s1, s2 ... with patternStr**
in the above two cases I should get the result true. As I am not bothering about the depth of the paths.

Case(2):

```
String patternStr = "hello/"

In this case, In the above two strings s1 only should match As the pattern is used to match with in the hello.
```

Please suggest me the better way to check this in groovy **with out** **regular** expressions.

Answer (score 4):

Groovy comes with Ant bundled, so you could just use ant's matcher:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.selectors.SelectorUtils

String patternStr = "hello/*"
String s1 = "hello/text"
String s2 = "hello/text/abcd"

assert SelectorUtils.match(patternStr, s1)
assert SelectorUtils.match(patternStr, s2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works for the above pattern(hello/*) well. But if the pattern is "hello/"  then it should only match with the string s1.  Need to consider one depth after hello. That means if we have any strings after hello like hello/text or hello/abc ...  for these strings the result should be true.

Comment: Should it?  I thought you'd need `hello/*` for single depth and `hello/**` for multi depth?  Try `matchPath` instead of `match`

Comment: String patternStr = "hello/"
        String s1 = "hello/text"        
        println(SelectorUtils.matchPath(patternStr, s1)) The result for the above I am getting false . But it should be true

Comment: Does ant return true for that?

Comment: No , it is returning false. But I am expecting true